# xcode 4.2 storyboard identifier

Tags: ios, xcode, hyperlink, storyboard, identifier

I'm writing an app in which I add some buttons to my view (mainView) by code. When the user taps on this buttons I want a new view (resultView) to show.

I have both of this views in my storyboard, but since there is no button on my mainView that is in storyboard I can't link the mainView and resultView to each other using storyboard. Everything must be done by code.

I want to know how I can link my two views by code and define an identifier for that link.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

To switch the view controller programmatically, you have to set a identifier in the attribute inspector at section "View Controller". After that, you can just use the value inside your code. Here i used the identifier "Menu".

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = self.storyboard;
MenuTableViewController *mtvc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Menu"];

[self presentViewController: mtvc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

There is also a description in the documentation, just look for

> Instantiating a Storyboard’s View Controller Programmatically

Answer (score 1):

Give the segue between the two an identifier in the *Attribute Inspector* in IB, then on your button press event call `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MySegueIdentifier" sender:theButton]`